# Make longer subplot tick marks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to alter the tick marks along the axes of a python multipanel subplot.  I have two panels that share a common x-axis.  I have made the border around the plot thicker as well as making all of the tick marks along the axes thicker.  I have two questions:

How can I make all tick marks (both axes) longer so they are more visible?

How do I add smaller but still noticable tick marks between major tick marks?

Here is a minimum working example of what I have so far.

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import *
from pylab import *
from random import *
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#make the axis border thick
pylab.rc("axes", linewidth=4.0)
pylab.rc("lines", markeredgewidth=4)


#create a figure with two panels that shares the x-axis
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=False)
#example figure1
ax1.plot(range(2),range(2),linewidth=2)
#example figure 2
ax2.plot(range(2),range(2),linewidth=2)



# Fine-tune figure; make subplots close to each other and hide x ticks for
# all but bottom plot.
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
show()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#example figure1
ax1.plot(range(2),range(2),linewidth=2)
ax1.minorticks_on()
ax1.tick_params('both', length=20, width=2, which='major')
ax1.tick_params('both', length=10, width=1, which='minor')
```

You can repeat the same for `ax2`. Does this work for you?

Comment: How can you get a list of available parameters of `axes.tick_params()`?

Comment: @Atcold they are here in the docs https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

Comment: To hide an unwanted tickmark, I ended up with (slightly different syntax) `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0, width=0, which='minor')`