# incorrect Colorbar for log values in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I want to use a scatter plot to describe the relationship between X, Y and Z. Z is p-value so it is better to denote it as log values.

Following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201172/a-logarithmic-colorbar-in-matplotlib-scatter-plot), I can plot a logarithmic scatter plot, but the color bar seems wrong. The color bar is almost totally blue, but there should be some red! Below is the figure and my codes.
[image]

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.set_title("P-value")

Z1 = pos_spearmanr['pval']
X = pos_spearmanr['X']
Y = pos_spearmanr['Y']

im = ax1.scatter(X,
                 Y, 
                edgecolors=None,
                c=Z1,
                norm=LogNorm(),
                cmap=plt.get_cmap('bwr'), alpha=0.2)

ax1.set_xlabel('X')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y')
ax1.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 1)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im,ax=ax1)
```

Comment: Any chance that `seaborn` messes with the colorbar? Have you tried losing that? Wait, I might be confusing `seaborn` itself with some style coming from that... EDIT: [yup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743220/getting-ticks-in-figure-with-subplots/34744812#34744812), nevermind. So: any fishy values in your `Z1`, something non-positive maybe?

Comment: I can't replicate this using either Python 2 or 3.  Can you confirm the versions you're using (Python versions, matplotlib versions, which OS etc).  I can see you've got some very low values for `Z1` (`10**-308` is notable as the smallest number IEEE double precision floats can store), but even making a pseudo dataset with numbers ranging from this value to 1, I can't replicate.