# bin DataFrame in pandas for heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to plot a heatmap from a DataFrame in pandas. The data looks like

`df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.random(100), "B": np.random.random(100), "C": np.random.random(100)})`

To show **how *C* changes as a function of *A* and *B***, I want to **bin the data based on *A* and *B* and calculate the average value of *C* in each bin, finally the heatmap has *A* and *B* as X-axis and Y-axis, and the color indicates the corresponding *C* value**.

I tried to use [Seaborn.heatmap](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), but the function accepts square dataset, which means I should *bin* the data first.

Is there a way to directly generate what I want from the DataFrame?
If not, how can I bin DataFrame into 2-D grids?

I know [pandas.cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.cut.html) can do the trick, but it seems only be able to cut based on one column one time. Of corse I can write tedious function to pipeline 'two cuts', but I am wondering if there is some *simple way* to do the task.

Scatter plot can give similar results but I want heatmap, something like [this](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004088/incorrect-colorbar-for-log-values-in-scatter-plot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> df.groupby([pd.cut(df.A, 3), pd.cut(df.B, 3)]).C.mean().unstack()
B                  (0.00223, 0.335]  (0.335, 0.666]  (0.666, 0.998]
A                                                                  
(0.000763, 0.334]          0.579832        0.454004        0.349740
(0.334, 0.667]             0.587145        0.677880        0.559560
(0.667, 1]                 0.566409        0.496061        0.420541
```